# Android sdk, Check if two or more files exist on sdcard

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So i have been looking a bit on the web and i found nothing really; I need a simple piece of code that will let me check if two files exist, If one of them does not, make a toast message error. Heres what i have tried (I thought it would work, lol)

```
if((file1 && file2.exists())){
    ... 
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some files are missing :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**RE-MAKE**
All i forgot was an extra ".exists()" on file1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the exists() call for file1 in the if-statement, i think

Comment: Haha, Yeah. Next time i must look at my code more carefully

Answer (score 1):

If "file1" and "file2" variables are of the File class in Android, then the only thing you're missing is the .exists() for "file1".

So your code would look like this:

```
if((file1.exists() && file2.exists())){
    ... 
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some files are missing :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```